# Error when trying to view data in PGAdmin4, PostgreSQL10, on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, pgadmin-4

I've installed PGadmin4 on my Ubuntu 22.04 system, with this repository :

> https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/$(lsb_release -cs) pgadmin4 main

PGAdmin4 runs, but if I want to see data from my postgreSQL tables (right-click on a table, then "View/Edit data"), or if I try a "select" query, PGadmin4 returns the error :

> "missing "from" clause entry for the table « rel » LINE 8: ...ER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_constraint con ON con.conrelid=rel.oid"

So I don't know which relation is missing, and why. My databases are correct : I'm using them with DBeaver without any problem. And my colleagues can access to them with PGAdmin4 for Windows without worries.

How can I see the whole underlying query?

Why Pgadmin can't view data from correct databases?

Do you have any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your database server version. Newest PgAdmin 7.version does not support PostgreSQL server 10. I had the same error on Postgres 10, and installing PgAdmin 6, everything worked fine.

Comment: Thank you very much @artis, my problem has been solved using "apt install pgadmin-server=6.21" and "apt install pgadmin-desktop=6.21".